# fileSystem to FTPFile[]?

Tags: java, junit4, mockito, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I simply want to know if there is a way to mock an array of FTPFile.
I am trying to pass as a parameter a fake FTPFile[] to the function I want to test:

```
protected void indexFolder(FTPClient, FTPFile[], File, FTPFolderAssetSource);
```

I am using FakeFtpServer to fake, as the name says, my ftp server. This library permit to fake the ftp content in this way:

```
        fileSystem = new WindowsFakeFileSystem();
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry1 = new DirectoryEntry("c:\\");
    directoryEntry1.setPermissions(new Permissions("rwxrwx---"));
    directoryEntry1.setOwner(USER1);

    FileEntry fileEntry1 = new FileEntry("c:\\data\\file1.txt", CONTENTS);
    fileEntry1.setPermissionsFromString("rw-rw-rw-");
    fileEntry1.setOwner(USER1);
    fileEntry1.setGroup(GROUP); 

    fileSystem.add(directoryEntry1);
    fileSystem.add(fileEntry1);

    ftp = new FakeFtpServer();
    ftp.setFileSystem(fileSystem);
```

Now, how can I use fileSystem to test my function who require FTPFile[] as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing specialy about the `FTPFile` class which would prevent mocking.  Unfortunately, using Mockito, [you can not mock arrays](http://groups.google.com/group/mockito/browse_thread/thread/e5d18eb15521447), as they are final.

This sample code should demonstrate the problem:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMockArrays {
  interface Animal {
    String getName();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMockArray() {
    final Animal[] mockArray = mock(Animal[].class);

    when(mockArray[0].getName()).thenReturn("cat");
    when(mockArray[1].getName()).thenReturn("dog");
    when(mockArray[2].getName()).thenReturn("fish");

    print1st3(mockArray);
  }

  public static void print1st3(final Animal[] animals) {
    System.out.println(animals[0].getName() + " " + animals[1].getName() + " " + animals[2].getName());
  }
}
```

Run it, and you'll see it results in an error message which makes explicit the problem:

**org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class [LTestMockArrays$Animal;**

**Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types**

The easiest solution is to use an extension to Mockito like [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which gets around certain restrictions to Mockito's mocking ability by using bytecode manipulation.  Then you could create the mock array by adding the following annotations to your junit test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // Need to run with Powermock runner
@PrepareForTest(FTPFile[].class) // We prepare FTPFile[] class for test because it's final
```

then in your test method you would create Mockito mock as normal:

```
FTPFile[] mockFTPFiles = mock(FTPFile[].class);
```